# regex: matching only first occurrence per line

Tags: regex

I want to select the first " - " from each line:

```
123 - foo - asdf
234 - bar - abcdefg
345 - foobar and hello world
```

If you use `\s-\s` it will select both occurrences from the first 2 lines.

So what I want is this:

[image]

I want 1 space, followed by a hyphen, followed by another space `\s-\s`, not just the hyphen and replace it with `test`, which is for the first line: `123testfoo - asdf`.

I think you have to add a `?` to make it non-greedy, but I don't know how.

Thanks.

Edit: **Here's the goal**:

I've got a huge file of IDs and Texts and I want to create an MySQL INSERT statement. So I want to replace the first `\s-\s` occurrence with `, '` (in that part).

Comment: Which regex flavour?

Comment: Also probably an X/Y problem, since "selecting" a specific constant text makes no sense (you know the text in advance, no need to go and extract it from another string). It may be interesting to tell us what you want to do once you've selected that text, e.g. validate the string format or transform it

Comment: Sublime Text. What causes the down votes? It's question I found no answer here for, sorry.

Comment: @FloBayer I didn't downvote, but it's probably because you didn't specify regex flavour. You also don't really have a question in your question (only what you want). You also don't specify intent with the characters you're trying to match and this matters in regex because if you're doing a replacement you'll need to capture certain parts to add them back in during the replacement (especially in your case), whereas if you're simply trying to match something you don't need to do that.

Comment: If you don't mind using `sed`, you can just do `sed s:-:/: file`. `awk` is also an option if the first `-` is always after the first space char `awk '{$2="/"; print $0}' file`

Comment: @ctwheels Okay, thanks for the feedback. I've got a huge file of IDs and Texts and I want to create an MySQL INSERT statement. So I want to replace the first `\s-\s` occurrence with `, '` (in that part).

Comment: @FloBayer you should update your question to include all relevant information. It helps us understand what exactly your needs are and allows us to find the best method to go about your problem. I think you're looking for [`^([^-]*?)\s*-\s*` replace with `$1, '`](https://regex101.com/r/JHUufH/8)

Comment: If you are substituting strings in every line of a file, you should **really** take a look at `sed`. It was made just for it.

Comment: @ctwheels Done. Thanks for that hint. Yup, that's want I'm searching for! Thank you. Do you want to create an answer, so we could mark it as solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To match the first occurrence on every line you need to anchor the pattern to the start of the line.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/JHUufH/8)

```
^([^-]*?)\s*-\s*
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `([^-]*?)` Capture any character except `-` any number of times, but as few as possible into capture group 1
- `\s*-\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters, followed by the hyphen `-` character, followed by any number of whitespace characters

Replacement: `$1, '`

The token `$1` is a reference to the text that was most recently captured by the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `$1` respectively `capture groups` is the keyword.

Comment: genius! helped me out of the box for a different symbol

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself with a similar problem but cannot fix it using accepted answer, try this:

I was trying to remove the first

```
','
```

from an sql exported data file, so as to merge people name with their surnames, example of data:
,

```
('MARTIN','MULLER QUEIJO',46574180,'1996-06-12','Dirección no definida','Dirección no definida','',3)
,('ALFREDO','ACOSTA',342,'23423','asdas','asdasd','',3)
,('JULIO','RODRIGUEZ',3223424202569,'42423','23fs','asdas','',3)
,('EVELIS (43)','MAIDANA CASCO',2342,'asdas','dfgdfg','3ggfd','',3)
```

To do so I ended up using this regex:

```
(',')(?=.*(',').*(',').*(','))
```

As you can see I get the first occurrence of my desired token (',') and discard the same token as many times as you predict it to appear in each line. SO this may only work if you already know how many times this token appears in the lines, and as long as it is the same amount of times for avery line (4 times in this case, so I removed it 3 times).

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookbehind to make sure there are no more hyphens in the line before your match:

```
(?<![-].*)(\s[-]\s)
```

Comment: That'll get the last hyphen. Also, you're doing a range from space character to space character. Now with the update you're no longer doing the range. Did you even test this?

Comment: @ctwheels , thank you for pointing that out. Fixed the regex.

Comment: That update is better and does work, but only in certain regex engines (notably [tag:.net]) because it uses a variable length lookbehind. Lookbehinds in sublime text need to be fixed length. Also, you don't need to put the hyphen inside a set `-` is the same as `[-]`

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<=(^[^-]*?))-/gm
```

This worked for me on the regexr website.
I'm unfortunately not sure what regexp flavor it works with

Uses lookbehind concept with grouping together with global and multiline flags
Seems to match any first occurrence of any character within a line just replace both the "-" with something else